# Are cp/rsync asynchronous?

Tags: bash, rsync, tar, cp

We're running a backup script which first copies a file to a destination and then runs `tar` over it.

```
DIR2BCK='/foo/bar'
TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
rsync -a ${DIR2BCK} ${TMPDIR}/ > /dev/null 2>&1
tar czf /tmp/foo.backup.tar ${TMPDIR}
```

After running this last command, sometimes the following warning is shown:

> /tmp/tmp.blqspkA136: file changed as we read it

We copy the destination to a temporary directory precisely to avoid file changes at compression time. This behavior is also reproducible when using the `cp` command instead of `rsync`. All my life I thought these commands were synchronous, but this warning seems to show the opposite.

If I put a `sleep` command between the `rsync`/`cp` and the `tar` lines, the warning doesn't show up, but I consider this a not quite clean solution.

Some facts:

- I tried adding a `sync` command between the `rsync` and `tar` commands with same result.
- As suggested by @jcbermu I also tried changing the script so the two lines are:

  ```
  rsync -a ${DIR2BCK} ${TMPDIR}/ > /dev/null 2>&1 &
  wait
  ```

  I run the script several times and some of them shown the same behavior, claiming the file changed when copying.
- The filesystem used is EXT4 both for `${TMPDIR}` and `${DIR2BCK}`.
- `${DIR2BCK}` is on a remote filesystem, actually this is a samba mountpoint of a remote machine. `${TMPDIR}` is on the local filesystem. However, changing `${DIR2BCK}` to the local filesystem makes no difference.
- All filesystems are hardware RAID-5 based.

Are these commands actually synchronous? If not, is there a way to make them so, or an alternative command?

Comment: Yes, these commands are done when they exit. You are not quoting file/directory names. Please fix that ASAP.

Comment: @DanielB My mistake. Although the logics is the same, this is not the actual code. The real one includes the quotes.

Comment: Well then perhaps there is a subtle mistake in the *real* code. Or is the code above actually enough to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes, it should be enough, as paths are correct. The major issue is that when `tar` starts, `rsync`/`cp` don't seem to have ended copying yet, and the warning is shown. I assumed these commands are synchronous, that's why I'm surprised.

Comment: Don’t assume, try. Otherwise, a qualified answer cannot be provided. // `sync` is not helping here. You’re not accessing raw data on devices. // Please also provide information about which filesystems both `$TMPDIR` and `$DIR2BCK` reside on.

Comment: Are both $TMPDIR and $DIR2BCK on the same filesystem? or are they separate drives or partitions? Are you using regular hard drives/ssd's or some sort of RAID?

Comment: @arielnmz they are on separate filesystems, `${TMPDIR}` is actually a samba share on a different machine, but this also happened when both where on the same filesystem. All filesystems are on RAID5.

Comment: What OS is in use on the receiving machine (e.g. Linux-based storage appliance?) and are there any processes in place on that system that might modify or access (change mtime or atime) a new file or directory, e.g. antivirus?  Also, what are the (non-authentication) mount options for the SAMBA filesystem (/tmp), and for the corresponding physical filesystem on the remote system? (e.g. noatime, directio, etc.)?  It seems like there may be some changes that aren't reflected back to the active system swiftly for some reason.  Also, why is the rsync output omitted, incl. errors? What errors show?

Comment: Just to rule it out: Which shell are you using? `rsync` and `cp` without `$` stay on foreground so those commands are definitly running synchronous in all shells I know. Unlikely, but of course an uncommon shell could execute them asynchronously, contradicting the common behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to rewrite it as:

```
rsync -a ${DIR2BCK} ${TMPDIR}/ > /dev/null 2>&1 ; tar czf foo.backup.tar ${TMPDIR}
```

So, `tar` won't start until `rsync` ends.

---

The other solution is to send the `cp`/ `rsync` to the background and wait until it ends with the command `wait`.

For example:

```
rsync -a ${DIR2BCK} ${TMPDIR}/ > /dev/null 2>&1 &
wait
tar czf foo.backup.tar ${TMPDIR}
```

The last `&` in the `rsync` line sends the execution to the background (it becomes a *child* of the current session), and then the `wait`forces this shell session to wait until all the children have finished to continue.

Comment: The problem with the first approach is that it is equivalent to the one I'm using. Splitting the two commands into two lines is the same as a one liner with the `;` as separator. None of them should make the `tar` line start until the `rsync`/`cp` commands have ended if they are synchronous, but that doesn't happen in this case. I'll try the second approach and get back.

Comment: Unfortunately the change you proposed showed the same behavior in some runnings, I edited my question adding this test.

Comment: Yes, the two proposed solutions and the code which the OP uses are all equivalent, so this cannot change something.

Answer (score -1):

> I put a sleep command between the rsync/cp and the tar lines, the warning doesn't show up, but I consider this a not quite clean solution.

Good for you or having standards.  What happens if, instead of sleep, you use:

> sudo sync; echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Do you consider that to be a good solution?

Note: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches seems to be what Ubuntu uses, and is not expected to be an approach that works on all Unixes (although maybe all Linuxes).  I'm mentioning it after having read https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=589975 and, after reading an initial report questioning the safety of doing this, reading more forum thread posts that confirm its safety.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question, but I already tried the `sync` command with no success. I tried both a local filesystem and a remote one as a destionation of the copy, but the same happens. The `drop_caches` is not good for us as we use a lot of different OS (CentOS, Ubuntu, Debian...).

Comment: `drop_caches` should exist on all those Linux distros: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#drop-caches. However, I cannot imagine how it could help. Check the comment by Slartibartfast at your question which points into more likely helpful directions.